# $\lim_ {x\rightarrow−2} \frac{1}{x + 1} = −1$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Been repeatedly stumped by this limits, epsilon-delta question: 
$\lim_
{x\rightarrow−2}
\frac{1}{x + 1} = −1$.
The answer in the back of Anton Transcendentals is: Min$(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$
I have tried manipulating it every which way, but cannot get my numbers to come out right, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you mean $\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{1}{x+1} = -1$? If so, start by writing down the definition and see where you can't go on.

Comment: Thanks Harnak. Is part of the definition 0< |x+2| < D [Capital D= Delta]

Comment: Yes, for each $\epsilon$ you have to find $\delta$ such that $0 < |x + 2| < \delta \implies |\frac{1}{x+1} +1 | < \epsilon$. So, basically, you need to solve last inequality to find a suitable $\delta$.

Comment: Hint: what would you do to calculate $lim_{x\to-1} 1/x$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=|\dfrac{1}{x+1}-(-1)|=|\dfrac{x-(-2)}{x+1}|.$

For $|x-(-2)| <1/2,$ we have

$-1/2 < x+2<1/2$, $-3/2 <x+1<-1/2$, i.e.

$|x+1| >1/2$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\min(1/2,\epsilon/2)$.

Then $|x-(-2)|<\delta$ implies

$f(x)=\dfrac{|x+2|}{|x+1|} < \dfrac{\delta}{1/2}= 2\delta <\epsilon.$

Answer (score -1):

If we set $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$, then
$$f(-2)=\frac{1}{-2+1}=-1\in\mathbb{R}$$

Hence,
$$\lim_{x\to-2}f(x)=f(-2)=-1$$

No need to manipulate the numbers .

Comment: The OP is trying to **prove** this via the limit definition.

Answer (score -1):

First, try to find an upper $B$ bound on $\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a}\right\rvert$ on some $\alpha$-neighborhood $(a-\alpha,a+\alpha)$ of $a$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a}\right\rvert&=&\left\lvert\frac{\frac{1}{x+1}-(-1)}{x-(-2)}\right\rvert\\
&=&\left\lvert\frac{x+2}{(x+1)(x+2)}\right\rvert\\
&=&\left\lvert\frac{1}{x+1}\right\rvert&
\end{eqnarray}

Now we want to find an $\alpha$-neighborhood  $(-2-\alpha,-2+\alpha)$. Usually, one chooses something simple, such as $\alpha=1$, but this time we will need something smaller such as $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$

$$ -\frac{5}{2}<x<-\frac{3}{2}$$

and look for an upper bound on $B$ on$\left\lvert\frac{1}{x+1}\right\rvert$ on that interval.

\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{5}{2}&<&x<-\frac{3}{2}\\
-\frac{3}{2}&<&x+1<-\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&<&-(x+1)<\frac{3}{2}\\
\frac{2}{3}&<&\left\lvert\frac{1}{x+1}\right\rvert<2
\end{eqnarray}

So $B=2$ is an upper bound on $\left\lvert\dfrac{\frac{1}{x+1}-(-1)}{x-(-2)}\right\rvert\ \text{when} -\frac{5}{2}<x<-\frac{3}{2}$

Now we are done with the preliminary investigations and are ready to present the actual proof that

$$ \lim_
{x\rightarrow−2}
\frac{1}{x + 1} = -1 $$

by using $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{B}\}$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$ and let $x\in(-2-\delta,2)\cup(-2+\delta)$. Then two things follow as a result:

1. $\left\lvert\frac{\frac{1}{x+1}-(-1)}{x-(-2)}\right\rvert<B$
2. $|x-(-2)|<\frac{\epsilon}{B}$

Thus, multiplying the two inequalities gives

$$ \left\lvert\frac{1}{x-1}-(-1) \right\rvert<\epsilon $$

Therefore,

$$ \lim_
{x\rightarrow−2}
\frac{1}{x + 1} = -1 $$

**ADDENDUM:** As an exercise, try using $\alpha=1$ rather than $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ and see why that fails for this particular limit.

Comment: Thanks so much John. I did get to the -5/2 < x < -3/2 stage myself, but then I got lost in where I was trying to go from there. Thanks for all your work, I'm finally seeing daylight!

Comment: This approach will work on limits where there is no vertical tangent and where an upper bound $B$ can easily be found.

Comment: I presume that my correct answer was downvoted because I provided a "too complete" answer to what was obviously a homework question.  But my experience is that students are frequently mystified by $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs, especially the way that $\delta$ is found. The customary "working backwards from the desired result" approach seems like "hand-waving" to some students. So for my students I use a "working forward" approach, illustrated in my answer to this question. I am glad the OP found it useful, even though it evidently rankled someone.

Comment: Sorry to hear that John, I found your answer very useful. I'm not at college, just doing math and physics in my own time for my own interest. I don't "cheat" by just looking at the answer on the internet, then thinking I understand. I put in several hours on that question, and finally had to apply for help here at stack exchange. Thanks again, your answer allowed me to go over it line by line and improve my understanding of (what I find to be) a difficult and hard to focus in the mind topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @CycloneCharlie.